# Query for a folder path containing //admin$

Tags: kibana, querydsl

I'm trying to write a query that returns all folder paths that contains admin share folders (admin$, c$ etc...)
It appears that I don't get the results for the $ but just anything that has "admin" in it.

This is the query:

```
{
   "query" : {

    "bool": {

      "must": [
        {"match_phrase_prefix": {"Process.Path": "*//admin$*"}}
      ]

   }
}
```

Any suggestions regarding this query? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [analyser could be dropping the special character](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-search-for-special-characters/41453).

I am also wondering if the `match_phrase_prefix` isn't doing a regex search, so perhaps escaping the special character like so `"*//admin\$*" could work?